# hosts file and multiple sub-domains

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, windows-xp, subdomain, localhost

For local testing (and learning), I wish to use x.com host name instead of localhost. I changed my Windows XP host file to this -

```
127.0.0.1       x.com
```

Now `http://x.com/` works beautifully but `http://www.x.com` doesn't. :(

What changes should I make so that www.x.com, sub1.x.com, sub2.x.com etc.. all work on local. Using WordpressMU users will be able to create and manage sub-domains dynamically.

I am basically trying to setup WordpressMU locally. I'm using Apache/2.2.4, PHP/5.2.4, and MySQL5.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've changed the IP for a single host `x.com` - You might be better off installing a local DNS server, and configuring the zones as you require (for instance, you could push email through a different MTA)

The quick solution would just be to add additional lines like:
127.0.0.1       www.x.com
127.0.0.1       sub1.x.com

Comment: Okay, so I need to a) Install a local DNS server and b) setup some zones there.

I would be grateful if you could suggest me a windows dns server and a link/book that tells me how to do all this crazy stuff. I'm excited :D

Comment: I think I need BIND and they have a manual too. Lets see if that works. Thanks.

Comment: I've certainly used Bind in the past -- mostly because that's what I use in production, so I could easily migrate the zone files...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this will require setting up a local DNS server, with zone files for these domains, as it's not possible to use wildcard domains in /etc/hosts

Answer (score 0):

As Rowland said, what you're asking for is wildcard DNS, and that requires a real DNS server.